# animate.css on first element of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, animate.css

I have an array that displays elements via ng-repeat.
When i add elements to the array I want them to flip in.

```
(js) $scope.tags.unshift(tag)

(css) .data-tag.ng-enter { animation:0.5s flipInX ease; }

(html) <div class="data-tag" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
```

the problem is that the animation is executed on the last element instead of the first. I need to use unshift() because i want the new element to appear first. the behaviour is as expected when using push() but then the order of the elements is not what i want (new elements get added to the bottom)

[image: Visual of behaviour]

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I used push instead of unshift in the end, this looks promising however: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9115